# Component rendering three times, not setting state the first time, throwing error: cannot read property of undefined

Tags: reactjs

Here are the relevant bits of my code:

```
class Edit extends NewForm {
  state = {};

  async componentWillMount() {
    const { data } = await axios.get("/entries/" + this.props.match.params.id);
    this.setState({ data });
  }

  render() {
    console.log("From render, ", this.state.data);
    return (
      <div>
        <div>Hello world</div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

When I run that, the console logs this.state.data three times. The latter two logs show that this.state.data is defined. But crucially, the first time it logs `undefined`. Like so

```
From render,  undefined
edit.jsx:63 
From render,  {_id: "5b9d4b794be5f60cdd2050d8", authors: Array(1), title: "Metaphysics", publisher: "Athens Press", year: "340 BC", …}
edit.jsx:63 
From render,  {_id: "5b9d4b794be5f60cdd2050d8", authors: Array(1), title: "Metaphysics", publisher: "Athens Press", year: "340 BC", …}
```

I suspect that it is a result of this first undefined state that if I try to access state in the render function, like this:

```
<p>{this.state.data.title}</p>
```

I get an error, like this:
[screenshot of error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tf5Rx.png)

You can actually see in the console in that image that this.state.data logs as undefined twice before the error. Anyone know what is going on here? Thanks ahead of time.

Comment: The data isn't ready yet so it will be undefined first. You need to do conditional check like {this.state.data && <p>{this.state.data.title}</p>} to get the title value

Answer (score 0):

First, I would fire the API call in `componentDidMount`, and then check if `data` is defined in your state.

Probably the first time you render your component, the request as not yet completed, thus it is still undefined.

I would do:

```
render() {
  const { data } = this.state;

  return (
    <div>
      <p>{data ? data.title : 'loading...'}</p>
    </div>
  );
```

Answer (score 0):

Your data is undefined first time. Initialize data like this.

```
state = { data: [] };
```

You can't print title like that, you have to loop.

```
  {
    this.state.data.map(item => {
      <p>{item.title}</p>;
    });
  }
```